# File not triggering automation, but then exact same file when manually dropped does trigger automation? (Automation Studio, Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio, ftp

I set up an automation that is triggered by a filedrop. When the file is dropped, it should be imported into a data extension. Also, when the automation runs, it kicks off a journey.

I've tested it multiple times and the filedrop has triggered the automation.

This morning, we went live and the filedrop did not trigger the automation. The automation was Active and waiting. The correct trigger file was in the correct directory with the correct naming pattern. I removed that trigger file from our FTP and then re-dropped the exact same file myself and the automation was triggered with no errors.

Has anyone experienced this? Is there potentially some problem with the way we are setting up the drop to the FTP?

[image: Automation ran successfully after I re-dropped the file myself]

[image: Filedrop information]

[image: Import File configuration]

[image: FTP config with the file I manually dropped that did trigger the automation]

[image: File trigger configuration]

Comment: Can you share your FTP and automation screen shots?

Comment: Hi, just added, thank you for asking!

Comment: Can you confirm the transfer method of the automated transfer?  I've seen instances of file-drop triggers not fired when files are dropped via SCP.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I will ask! Do you happen to know any other ways that automated transfers could be set up?

Comment: It depends on the platform sending the files, but it's generally either scp or sftp.

Comment: Are you using filename pattern in your trigger? And if yes - can you share the details?

Comment: @LukasLunow I am adding a screenshot, but my trigger filename pattern is Contains New_Customer_Data (so with no suffix). I'm also pretty sure that the folder I dropped into is set up correctly because when I did the drop manually, the automation triggered. When my colleague did the drop, the automation did not trigger

Answer (score 2):

Here is my theory. I assume you are utilising a filename suffix in your trigger filename pattern: *New_Customer_Data_Report%%Day%%%%Month%%%%Year%%**.csv***

Some FTP integrations, especially when dealing with large files, tend to create a file with a different suffix while uploading the data (and while data is not complete) before renaming it to the right suffix. This temporary suffix can be, e.g. *.part*

Once the SFTP connection is initiated and the file starts uploading, the trigger "sees" a .part file, and will not trigger. If you remove the suffix from your filename pattern, the trigger should work fine.

When you set up the File Import Activity itself, you should use `%%BASEFILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%.csv` as the file arriving to the FTP has a *.part* suffix, until it has finished uploading from the external source. If you would use `%%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%` the import will fail, as it will be looking for *TEST02.csv.part*

You can find additional best practices for importing files [on this page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_subscriber_import_file_requirements.htm&type=5). Reference for file name patterns [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_filename_patterns_reference.htm&type=5). And my favourite: [Substitution Strings Example](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_substitution_strings_example.htm&type=5).

Comment: The partial file issue is what I've experienced with the scp method of transferring files.